# Java IllegalMonitorStateException when using thread.wait();

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I'm new to using threads I get an IllegalMonitorStateException as soon as the wait method is called can someone help me out

```
public class SomeClass{

    private final Thread thread = new Thread(this::someMethod);

    public synchronized void someMethod(){
        try {
            doSomething();
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            doSomething();
            thread.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        someMethod();
    }

    public synchronized void restartThread() {
        thread.notify();
    }
```

```
        SomeClass test = new SomeClass();
        test.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

`wait` and `notify` methods can only be called on the monitor object, for which you have acquired a lock.
In your case you acquired a lock on the object of type `SomeClass`, however you try to call those methods on the monitor of the `thread` object.
Instead you should just call `wait();` and `notify();` in your code, which will call them on `this` object, which is exactly the same object for which you acquired a lock with `synchronized` keyword on the methods.